# Performance difference between comparing to an expression or a variable

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm wondering about the difference in performance, if any, between handling control flow with an expression and assigning that expression to a variable and comparing to that instead.
For example, what would be the difference in performance between:

```
double testVal = pow((point.x-center.x), 2.0) + (pow((point.y-center.y), 2.0));
double radSqr = pow(radius, 2.0);
if(testVal < radSqr) {
....................
} else if(testVal == radSqr) { 
..................
}
```

and

```
if(pow((point.x-center.x), 2.0) + (pow((point.y-center.y), 2.0)) < pow(radius, 2.0)) {
....................
} else if(testVal == radSqr) { 
..................
}
```

Comment: any optimizing compiler would fix that for you, don't sweat the small stuff

Comment: The difference is that the first code is compiling without errors and the other is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question and here is a good and fun-to-read article why: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

If you really would have to know the answer measuring is you friend if done right: http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one